# jQuery When After Each Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, .when

I have six static html questions and then 3-4 questions being generated by JSON dynamically based upon a form choice made on a page before. What I'm trying to do is generate the questions, then create a progress bar based on the final number of questions created. Where I'm having trouble is using the jQuery when done method after my each loop. It is firing after the first iteration instead of the last. I have tried populating an array "Qs" and passing the array, after reading some other posts, but what I have hasn't worked. I would really like to segment my code and clean it up as much as possible, so I'm trying to stay away from nesting it.

```
  var Qs = [];
  var generateQs = function (){
    var $dept = sessionStorage.getItem("sFGeneralDepartment1");
    var $qWrapper = $("#assessmentTool");
      $.getJSON("js/dept-questions.json", function(data) {
        var key = $dept;
        var vals = [];
        switch(key) {
          case 'Information technology':
            vals = data.IT;
            break;
          case 'Finance':
            vals = data.FIN;
            break;
          case 'Human resources':
            vals = data.HR;
            break;
          case 'Marketing':
            vals = data.MKT;
            break;
          default:
            vals = data.OT;
          break;
         }
         $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
           var $cleanID = (value.qID).replace(/q/g, '');
           $qWrapper.append('<div class="question-container rangeIcon disabled" id="' + value.qID + '"><p>Question ' + $cleanID +'</p> <h4>' + value.questionText + '</h4><ul class="answer-container"></ul></div>');
           $.each(value.answers, function(i, answer) {
             var $aID = answer.aID;
             var $radioBtn = '<div class="radioBtn"><span class="radioBtnInner"></span></div>';
             $('.question-container#' + value.qID + ' .answer-container').append('<li class="survey-item"><div class="icon-holder" id="' + $aID + '"><img src="img/' + answer.iconFileName + '" width="' + answer.iconWidth +'" height="'+ answer.iconHeight + '"/></div><input type="radio" id="'+ $aID + '" value="' + answer.pointValue + '"><label for="' + $aID + '" class="radio" data-popover="'+ answer.popoverText + '">' + $radioBtn + '<span class="labelTopText">' + answer.labelTopText + '<span class="divider">/</span></span><span class="labelBottomText">' + answer.labelBottomText + '</span></label></li>');
           });
           Qs.push($cleanID);
         });
         console.log('done');
         console.log(Qs);
       });
     };
     $.when(generateQs($,Qs)).done(function() {
       //create progress bar
       console.log('starting');
       var qCount = ($('.question-container').length + 1);
       var qList = $('#progressBar');
       for (var i = 0; i < qCount; i++){
         qList.append('<li class="progress-bar-steps" data-item="q' + (i+1) + '">' + '<span class="step-text">' + (i+1) + '</span>' + '</li>');
           $('.question-container').each(function (i, value){
             var qId = $(this).attr('id');
             if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                 $(this).css('opacity','1.0');
                 $('#progressBar').find("[data-item='" + qId + "']").addClass('active').html('<span class="step-text">' + (i+1) + '</span>');
                 $('.progress-bar-steps.active').next('.progress-bar-steps').addClass('next disabled-next').html('<span class="step-text">' + (i+2) + '</span>');
             } else {
               $(this).addClass('disabled');
             }
           });
         }
      });
```

Comment: try adding `return $.getJSON("js/dept-questions.json", function(data) { ... });`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was missing! Thank you!